# Symfony2: Edit file upload

Tags: file-upload, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I am using the cookbook article from symfony.com to implement a file upload option for images.

Now I want to load up other images to the entity.

The default strategy for editing is:
 1. Fetch out of DB
 2. Inject into Form
 3. Persist

Somehow this strategy doesn't work anymore when using file uploads (doctrine doesn't execute the events)

What else could I do to make the articles with picture editable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cookbook does **not handle updates**, in particular in the case where only the file changes.

In this case, the `PreUpdate` event is not triggered, so you need to trigger `$entity->preUpload()` manually before the `$em->persist($entity)`, so that the file upload gets handled in any case (preUpload will alter `$entity->path` so the persisting will occur)

Comment: Hi,
youre right. When no field is updated the lifecycle callback events doesn't get fired :)

Comment: If you use the Knp DoctrineExtensions, you can use Timestampable on the entity holding the file upload logic and use $entity->updateTimestamps(); before $em->persist() so it will updated the dummy fields you need ;)

Answer (score 7):

If you change only the upload field the lifecycle not run the upload method, In the cookbook is reported the solution in a quote box as below:

> The PreUpdate and PostUpdate callbacks are only triggered if there is
>   a change in one of the entity's field that are persisted. This means
>   that, by default, if you modify only the $file property, these events
>   will not be triggered, as the property itself is not directly
>   persisted via Doctrine. One solution would be to use an updated field
>   that's persisted to Doctrine, and to modify it manually when changing
>   the file.

add a dummy field to update in the controller before persist event as suggest by this duscussion:

https://github.com/symfony/symfony-docs/pull/564

```
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have was in similar situation.
I try to edit existing record in database with path to the file.
When i edit record i must upload new file, what is not comfortable for users.
In my solution i use variable tmp file for file hash and variable file name.
All needed operation i made in Action edit class.

Full example action class in bellow link

https://github.com/marekz/php_examples/wiki/Symfony-how-to-edit-attachment-form