# Embedded file on Symfony 2.8 edit form doesn't works

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-forms

I've added an embedded File form into my User form so I can add a profile picture for each user. The creation of the user form and the associated image is OK. But when I want to edit an user, I cannot manage to edit the embedded file.

This is my Media (file) Entity:

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Media
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Media", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_Media_Cat_Media1_idx", columns={"Cat_Media_ID"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Media
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Libelle", type="string", length=45, nullable=true)
     */
    private $libelle;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ID", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Cat_Media_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     * })
     */
    private $catMedia;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;

    private $tempFilename;

    private $file;

    /**
     * Set libelle
     *
     * @param string $libelle
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setLibelle($libelle)
    {
        $this->libelle = $libelle;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get libelle
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLibelle()
    {
        return $this->libelle;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set catMedia
     *
     * @param \AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia $catMedia
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setCatMedia(\AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia $catMedia = null)
    {
        $this->catMedia = $catMedia;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get catMedia
     *
     * @return \AdminBundle\Entity\CatMedia 
     */
    public function getCatMedia()
    {
        return $this->catMedia;
    }

    /**
     * Set url
     *
     * @param string $url
     * @return Media
     */
    public function setUrl($url)
    {
        $this->url = $url;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get url
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUrl()
    {
        return $this->url;
    }

    /**
     * Set alt
     *
     * @param string $alt
     * @return string
     */
    public function setAlt($alt)
    {
        $this->alt = $alt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get alt
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function getAlt()
    {
        return $this->alt;
    }

    /**
     * Set file
     *
     * @param string $file
     * @return string
     */
    public function setfile($file)
    {
        $this->file = $file;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get file
     *
     * @return Media
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif)
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // Le nom du fichier est son id, on doit juste stocker également son extension
        // Pour faire propre, on devrait renommer cet attribut en « extension », plutôt que « url »
        $this->url = $this->file->guessExtension();

        // Et on génère l'attribut alt de la balise <img>, à la valeur du nom du fichier sur le PC de l'internaute
        $this->alt = $this->file->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        // Si jamais il n'y a pas de fichier (champ facultatif)
        if (null === $this->file) {
            return;
        }

        // Si on avait un ancien fichier, on le supprime
        if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
            $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->tempFilename;
            if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
                unlink($oldFile);
            }
        }

        // On déplace le fichier envoyé dans le répertoire de notre choix
        $this->file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(), // Le répertoire de destination
            $this->id.'.'.$this->url   // Le nom du fichier à créer, ici « id.extension »
        );
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PreRemove()
     */
    public function preRemoveUpload()
    {
        // On sauvegarde temporairement le nom du fichier, car il dépend de l'id
        $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->id.'.'.$this->url;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        // En PostRemove, on n'a pas accès à l'id, on utilise notre nom sauvegardé
        if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
            // On supprime le fichier
            unlink($this->tempFilename);
        }
    }

    public function getUploadDir()
    {
        // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour un navigateur
        return '/uploads/img';
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // On retourne le chemin relatif vers l'image pour notre code PHP
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    public function getWebPath()
    {
        return $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->getId().'.'.$this->getUrl();
    }
}
```

This is my User Controller Edit Action:

```
/**
 * Displays a form to edit an existing Utilisateur entity.
 *
 * @Route("/{id}/edit", name="utilisateur_edit")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Utilisateur $utilisateur)
{
    $this->get('logger')->info("on est dans le UTILISATEUR CONTROLLER");
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($utilisateur);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('AdminBundle\Form\UtilisateurType', $utilisateur);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($utilisateur);
        $password = $encoder->encodePassword($editForm->get('password')->getData(), $utilisateur->getSalt());
        $utilisateur->setPassword($password);
        $utilisateur->setUsername($editForm->get('mail')->getData());

       // test try from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962882/symfony2-edit-file-upload
       /* $media = $utilisateur->getMedia();
        $media->upload();*/

        $em->persist($utilisateur);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('utilisateur_edit', array('id' => $utilisateur->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('AdminBundle:utilisateur:edit.html.twig', array(
        'utilisateur' => $utilisateur,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

I found this other [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9962882/symfony2-edit-file-upload) during my problem research, but I do not know how to apply this proposal to my code. And I also do not really know if this approach will solve my problem...

Thank's in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What the "solution" is suggesting is basically to modify any other field from your entity in order for Doctrine to pick the changes up.

This would require you to add yet another field to your *Media* entity (updatedAt is a good example) which you'd modify every time you save the entity:

```
class Media
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    public function updateNow()
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime('now', new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt
    }

    ...
```

Then in your method that sets a new file, you can set this new property to "fool" Doctrine in thinking that something has changed and the preUpdate life cycle callback needs to be triggered:

```
/**
 * Set file
 *
 * @param string $file
 * @return string
 */
public function setfile($file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    $this->updateNow();

    return $this;
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Hey @hasumedic ! thank you for your help. i have the error "DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given" on updateNow function:$this->updatedAt = new \DateTime(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));

Comment: Hey @hasumedic ! Thanks again for you're help :)  i have now the error: "The file "/tmp/phpT48rJp" does not exist" when i try to edit a media. No problem when i create a new Media. did i forget something (in my controller maybe ?)